# Colmn selection case insensitive in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, oracle

I am trying to get data from a table which is having its column in upper case. I am using mysql, oracle databases for the same application. I need all the columns in lower case beacuse of some aggregate error for laravel pagination.

```
ex - Model::select('tablename.COLUMN_1', 'tablename.COLUMN_2');
```

It is working on oracle when using **column_1** and **column_2** at blade view file but not in mysql so I did one thing - changed query to -

```
Model::select('tablename.COLUMN_1 as column_1', 'tablename.COLUMN_2 as column_2');
```

It is working in that case.
Is there any other solution to this problem as I do not want to alias every column for every query. May be laravel provides something.

Comment: Is there any reason your database has to remain its schema? Because it's a better approach to make them lower_case in MySQL.

Comment: @CloudSohJunFu actually it's best to use ascii, lowercase, replace spaces with underscore in every SQL database server not only just MySQL, it is just plain irritanting that Oracle converts to [uppercase](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1593eb0af3064503f6840ab982fa7d0e) indentifiers..

Comment: [lower_case_table_names](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lower_case_table_names) might help, if the server is yours to control as the setting needs to go in the server config and a restart is required.

Comment: *"I need all the columns in lower case beacuse of some aggregate error for laravel pagination."* In that case laravel has made a wierd limiting case here.  As i don't read annything in the [manual](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/pagination) it can't be uppercase columns name..  Maybe you should show some more code where you use a Paginator and show the error.. Otherwise it might be a case of [Manually Creating A Paginator](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/pagination#manually-creating-a-paginator)